# amcharts4 proper way to handle zero values on logarithmic value axis

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I want to display some data with high variety in amcharts4, so I like to use the logarithmic scale on the value axis. Unfortunately the data contain some zero values, which of course can't be displayed with logarithmic scale.

I tried to change the zero values to 1 before rendering the chart, which would work, but now the values are not correct any more.

```
data.forEach(item => {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (item[key] === 0) {
      item[key] = 1;
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any better way to handle zero values with logarithmic value axis, that I can display the correct data?

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omrZZM) is a code pen, which shows my current solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

As of version 4.9.34, [`treatZeroAs`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#treatZeroAs_property) is officially supported. Just set it on the value axis to the desired value to remap your zero values to:

```
valueAxis.treatZeroAs = 0.1;
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/67cca93ecb93e5f889872dd6d18eb0ae?editors=0010).

The below workaround isn't needed anymore, but you may find the value axis adapter snippet helpful in changing the first label when using `treatZeroAs`.

**Old method - pre 4.9.34**

There doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent to v3's `treatZeroAs` property, which automatically handled this sort of thing. Pre-processing the data is one step, but you can also copy the original value into a separate object property and use a series tooltip adapter to dynamically show your actual value:

```
data.forEach(item => {
  for (const key in item) {
    if (item[key] <= 0) {
      item[key+"_actual"] = item[key]; //copy the original value into a different property
      item[key] = 1;
    }
  }
});
// ...

//display actual data that was re-mapped if it exists
chart.series.each((series) => {
  series.adapter.add("tooltipText", (text, target) => {
    if (target.dataFields) {
      let valueField = target.dataFields.valueY;
      let tooltipData = target.tooltipDataItem;
      if (tooltipData.dataContext[valueField + "_actual"] !== undefined) { 
        return '{' + valueField + '_actual}';
      }
      else {
        return text;
      }
    }
    else {
      return text;
    }
  })
});
```

If you want to fake a zero label, you can use an adapter for that as well since your smallest value in this case will be 1:

```
//fake the zero axis label
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", (text) => {
  if (text === "1") {
    return "0"
  }
  else {
    return text;
  }
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/99726f7d52fe7252b54f85eb483259e6?editors=0010)

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. I just replaced the `1` values with `1.3` to show a difference between `0` and `1`.

Comment: The globalAdapter doesn't appear to work in the example

Comment: @Scot - thanks for the heads up. Seems like something changed in a recent release. I'll ping the developers.

Comment: @Scot - apologies for the delayed response. As the developers are officially deprecating global adapters, I've updated the demo to use local, series-level adapters instead. I hope this helps!

Comment: As of version 4.9.34, [`treatZeroAs`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/valueaxis/#treatZeroAs_property) is officially supported. The adapter solution is no longer needed, but you might find the value axis adapter useful for changing the first label with `treatZeroAs`.